# Insert string at compile-time

Tags: java, svn, twitter

I'm currently developing a Java-application working with Twitters OAuth-API. This needs 2 keys which must be kept secret. I want my application to be open-source like hosting my code on Google Project Hosting, so I want to insert a placeholder for the key-string and fill it from an unversioned file at compile-time.

Is this possible using Netbeans?

Comment: *"..working with Twitters OAuth-API. This nerds.."*  I always suspected that Twitterers were nerds, geeks or freaks.  ;)

Answer (score 3):

The simpliest way: create a properties file (for example `oauth_keys.properties`) and place it in the classpath (if you use netbeans you probably use maven as build system, it is in the directory `src/main/resources`/). Then, during startup, load the keys using `ClassLoader.getResource()` or throws an exception if the properties file is not found.

Comment: +1 Using `ClassLoader.getResource()` is definitely a good idea.